# Mysql count query that calculates a total

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to modify a count query so I can the output onto a webpage. Current code is:

```js
$db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(`SubmissionId`) FROM #__forms WHERE FormId='8' ");

echo "So far we have <strong>".$db->loadResult()."</strong> submissions";
```

It works fine as it shows the number of submisisons where the value in the formid is 8.
**But** I also want to include in the sum formid 4 and 5 so I have a combined total.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query for: `"SELECT COUNT(SubmissionId) FROM #__forms WHERE FormId IN ('8','4','5')"`

Comment: You know what, I had been trying the IN option but for some reason I must had missed something. Now working.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
"SELECT COUNT(SubmissionId) FROM #__forms WHERE FormId='8' OR FormId='4' OR FormId='5'"
```